# How can I edit the attributes in a JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
[{ ID: '0001591',
    name: 'EDUARDO DE BARROS THOMÉ',
    class: 'EM1A',
    'phone Pai': '(11) 999822922',
    'email Pai': 'sergio7070@globo.com',

  { ID: '0001592',
    name: 'JEAN LUC EUGENE VINSON',
    class: 'EM1A',
    'phone Pai': '(11) 981730534',
    'email Pai': 'jeanpevinson@distock.com.br',
```

And I wish that looks like that:

```
[{ ID: '0001591',
    name: 'EDUARDO DE BARROS THOMÉ',
    class: 'EM1A',
    Address[
        type:Phone,
        tag:Pai,
        address:'(11) 999822922',
]
Address[
        type:Email,
        tag:Pai,
        address:'sergio7070@globo.com',
]

 },
  { ID: '0001592',
    name: 'JEAN LUC EUGENE VINSON',
    class: 'EM1A',
Address[
        type:Phone,
        tag:Pai,
        address:'(11) 981730534',
]
Address[
        type:email,
        tag:Pai,
        address:'jeanpevinson@distock.com.br',
]
     } ]
```

Do you have any suggestions, please?

Comment: You have an array of objects. You need to supply an index of the object you want to access:

    `data[0].name = "Some new name";`

Comment: Btw. that's not a valid JSON.

Comment: @Shomz I think he added `<br/>` because he wanted to force new lines here on SO. I removed it for that reason.

Comment: @TomášZato, yes, probably that's the reason. But there's more - the keys need to be quoted as well.

Comment: @Shomz actually, you're right, it's totally broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing your JSON a bit, let's say you have this JS object (btw. it's still an invalid JSON, but a valid JS object):

```
var json = [{ ID: '0001591',
    name: 'EDUARDO DE BARROS THOMÉ',
    class: 'EM1A',
    'phone Pai': '(11) 999822922',
    'email Pai': 'sergio7070@globo.com'
  },
  { ID: '0001592',
    name: 'JEAN LUC EUGENE VINSON',
    class: 'EM1A',
    'phone Pai': '(11) 981730534',
    'email Pai': 'jeanpevinson@distock.com.br'
   }];
```

It's a two-element array, with each array element being an object, so to access each object, you need to use an index, for example:

```
json[0];
json[1];
```

To access a specific property of an object, you need to use the key, for example:

```
json[0].name;
json[0]['name']; // equal to above, but you'll need it for your keys with spaces
```

Finally to add an object property, we can do something like this:

```
json[0].Address = []; // make it an empty array
json[0].Address.push({
    type: 'Phone',
    tag: 'Pai',
    address: '(11) 999822922'}); // push the phone number

json[0].Address.push({
    type: 'Email',
    tag: 'Pai',
    address: 'sergio7070@globo.com'}); // push the email
```

That will give you the final object you asked for.

If you wish to make it automatic (I see you're reading `'phone Pai'` and `'email Pai'` values to build those new objects), you'd need to loop the whole array, parse the object keys to figure out the types and tags, and finally add an object property to each object based on the parsed data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and wasn´t me who give to you a downvote, sorry for this creature

Comment: You're welcome, hope you managed to pull it off. Yes, it's someone who downvoted your question as well... luckily, there's A LOT of great people here at StackOverflow, don't let those few others bring you down.